# JointJs - Discarding the command in CommandManager.cmdBeforeAdd

Tags: javascript, jointjs

In my JointJs application, I want to discard particular commands so that they are not added in the Undo/Redo stack.

I followed the exact same code snippet from the JointJs [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v3.6/dia.CommandManager.html) like below:

```
var commandManager = new joint.dia.CommandManager({
    graph: graph,
    cmdBeforeAdd: function(cmdName, cell, graph, options) {
        options = options || {};
        return !options.ignoreCommandManager;
    }
});

// ...

// Note that the last argument to set() is an options object that gets passed to the cmdBeforeAdd() function.
element.set({ 'z': 1 }, { ignoreCommandManager: true });
```

But when I look into the `options` object in the debug mode, it doesn't contain any property with the name `ignoreCommandManager`.

I have also tried the below call to set the z value but it didn't work either.

```
element.set('z', 1 , { ignoreCommandManager: true });
```

Any idea why the options object is missing this property to ignore the command, please?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, It was failing in Firefox when I posted the question here. The cache was also disabled.

I tried in another browser (Chrome) today without introducing any new changes and it was working without any issues.